# Working within a large network with multiple private IP subnets

Tags: ip, routing, private-network

In a very large corporate network, the entire corporate network consists of many various subnets, all within private IP space.  There are, of course, many routes out to public IP land, but a given packet within the private network may route from 10.0.0.0 networks, through 192.168.0.0 networks, to get to a 172.16.0.0 target.  Obviously, this all works well as long as routes are working as intended.

The question I have is in implementing a segregated group of hardware behind a NAT within this network. Am I right in anticipating a potential problem, if the NAT'd network is using an IP address in a private space that also exists out elsewhere in the corporate private super-network?  I'm guessing most traffic will work just fine - unless it happens to need to route through a subnet that is the same as the origin or destination, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are rift to anticipate a problem, but yes it should mostly work OK.

When your stuff us behind NAT the IP addresses don't matter as long as they are unique. Nevertheless this can potentially create a few problems.

If another part of the network has an IP in the same range as your NATTED network you won't be able to talk to it because your network won't route it out the gateway. Similarly, machines outside your NAT network won't be able yo reach in to it, which might be desirable or might frustrate remote administrators.

Answer (score 1):

> Implementing a segregated group of hardware behind a NAT within this network.

So from the point of view of the rest of the network, all outgoing connections from this group of hardware will seem to originate from the router that does the NAT. This router will have an address in at least one of the existing segments, and those segments should have unique prefixes.

> Am I right in anticipating a potential problem, if the NAT'd network is using an IP address in a private space that also exists out elsewhere in the corporate private super-network?

So no, this won't be a problem.

> I'm guessing most traffic will work just fine - unless it happens to need to route through a subnet that is the same as the origin or destination, correct?

No, because while going through the subnet, the IP address the subnet sees are that of the router.

What you **will** have trouble with are (1) incoming connections into the NAT (won't be possible, though you can setup port forwarding on the NAT machine for at least some), and (2) too many outgoing connections from the NAT, which will overflow the translation table in the NAT router.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware that things outside would only see it as the NAT's IP address, but for some reason I thought it might still have a problem navigating a remote network that has the same subnet as the source - but after thinking about it, I do see how that would not be a problem.  I think i got myself stuck on how a tracert would work, as a tracert from within the NAT would not be able to directly ping the individual steps along the way that ARE in the same subnet - but tracert not working doesn't mean the packets won't still be able to get to the destination.